# MKMapView - how to calculate radius consistent with set-up

Tags: ios, mkmapview

I draw a circle on an MKMapView. But how do I calculate the radius of this circle such that it equals the value of the radius used to draw the circle in the first place?

```
func setArea(_ center:CLLocationCoordinate2D, radius:CLLocationDistance) {

    let area = MKCircle(center:center, radius:radius / LocationViewController.kRadiusInset)
    mapView.setVisibleMapRect(mapView.mapRectThatFits(area.boundingMapRect), animated:false)
}
```

I've tried the following but it returns a value very slightly larger than `radius` passed to `setArea`. It calculates the distance from the center of the map to the left-hand edge.

```
// getRadius
let distance = middle.distance(from: edge)
let middle = CLLocation(latitude: mapView.region.center.latitude, longitude: mapView.region.center.longitude)
let edge = CLLocation(latitude: mapView.region.center.latitude, longitude: mapView.centerCoordinate.longitude - (mapView.region.span.longitudeDelta * 0.5))

 let distance = middle.distance(from: edge)
```

If I pass in '4000' metres to `setArea()` and then afterwards calculate the map's radius (say, within `mapViewDidFinishRenderingMap()` I get `4010.61219348448`

Why the discrepancy?

Answer (score 0):

I replaced the use of a MKCircle with the following:

```
let region = MKCoordinateRegionMakeWithDistance(center, radius * 2, radius * 2)
mapView.region = region
```

This is less inaccurate. With radius == 4000 fed into this I get 4000.00048143541 after I set my MKMapView's `region`. This difference will creep into the user-interface but not nearly as quickly as my first approach.

Can anyone get closer?